# Taylor series expression of the function.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose we are given the following function.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}[x\sqrt{1-x^2} +\sin^{-1}x]$$. Write down the Taylor series expansion about the origin, up to term involving $x^7$, for the function.

This problem was asked in a mathematics exam where students have to solve 40 questions in 150 minutes.

I know the routine method but it is too lengthy.

Is there a more easy("Think out of the box") like approach to solve it.

Comment: Differentiate it?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is just$$\int_0^x\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$